# show that if det()=0 with A, and B, then AB = BA.

Tags: linear-algebra

show that if

|b c|

|a b| = 0

with 
A =

[a a]

[b b] ,

and B =

[b b]

[c c], then AB = BA.

I'm not exactly sure how to go about proving this. I tried computing both AB and BA, then factoring out the letters so its multiplied by the [1] matrix, and taking the determinent of both making them both 0, and i tried expanding the factored out letters and setting them equal to eachother but couldnt really solve or prove anything, i tried taking the first determinent showed to get b^2 -ac = 0 but couldnt really do anything with it either.. how do I approach this..

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical typesetting

Comment: Where is the problem from?  Why do you think this is true?

Comment: The first condition gives you no information about $d$. What if $a = b = c = 1$, but $d = 1000$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer the problem is from my teachers homework packet. I have no idea.

Comment: @platehead i'm not sure.

Comment: Well it's clear enough that $\left|\begin{matrix} b & c \\ a & b \end{matrix}\right| = 0$. If you've computed $AB$ and $BA$, you should see that they're not actually equal...

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I miss-typed the A matrix when posting the question, it should have no d's. but everything I tried on paper was with the correct letters. It is edited now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $b^2-ac=0$, then $b^2=ac$. Then,
$$AB=\left(\begin{matrix} a & a \\ b & b \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} b & b \\ c & c \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} ab+ac & ab+ac \\ b^2+bc & b^2+bc \end{matrix}\right)$$
$$BA=\left(\begin{matrix} b & b \\ c & c \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} a & a \\ b & b \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} ab+b^2 & ab+b^2 \\ ac+bc & ac+bc \end{matrix}\right)$$
The above matrices $AB$ and $BA$ are equal if every entry in $AB$ is equal to the corresponding entry in $BA$. Since we know that $b^2=ac$ *(since that's given to us)*, we can substitute accordingly, and see that yes, $AB$ in fact equals $BA$.